# DateTimeFormatter single digit month

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to parse a date where the month goes from 1 to 12 (And not from 01 to 12).

I'm trying this:

```
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[[MM][M]yyyy").parse("112019"));
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[[MM][M]yyyy").parse("82019"));
```

The first line works, the second fails.

Even Myyyy fails to parse the second line. I have not been able to find any pattern able to parse 82019 :(

[M][MM] as well as [MM][M] fail. Reading the documentation it says:

> M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J

So M is supposed to parse both 8 and 11.

Anyone has been able to get something working?

This works:
`System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-yyyy").parse("8-2019"));`
But the data I got don't have any separation between the month and the year.

Comment: Yes, month is always there.  Myyyy doesn't work. ```System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Myyyy").parse("82019"));``` returns ```Text '82019' could not be parsed at index 5```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` is what you are looking for:

```java
String s = "112019";
System.out.println(new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("M")
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
        .toFormatter()
        .parse(s)
);
```

Comment: This one takes ~90 seconds per billion @ 8 x 3.4 GHz (7 Threads). Well done!

Answer (score 3):

```
    DateTimeFormatter yearMonthFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
            .toFormatter();

    System.out.println(YearMonth.parse("112019", yearMonthFormatter));
    System.out.println(YearMonth.parse("82019", yearMonthFormatter));
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 2019-11
> 2019-08
> ```

Unintuitively (but very practical in many other situations) a single pattern letter for a numerical field does not mean 1 digit, but as many digits as it takes. So `M` is not what we need here. What we do need instead is a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `appendValue` method, which comes in a number of overloaded versions. What we use for parsing fields that haven’t got any delimiter between them is known as *adjacent value parsing*. java.time can do this when all fields except the first have fixed widths, which you fulfil nicely.

I prefer to parse into a `YearMonth`, it’s a perfect match for the information in your strings, but that’s not the point here.

**Link:** [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendValue(TemporalField, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValue(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,int)) explaining adjacent value parsing.

Answer (score 2):

If all of your dates are given in the format you provided, consider isolating the values like so:

```
String s = "112019";
int yearIndex = s.length() - 4;
String pretty = s.substring(0, yearIndex) + " " + s.substring(yearIndex);
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[M] yyyy").parse(pretty));
```

Comment: This probably works, but I have billions of dates to process so I was trying to avoid extra manipulation and objects creation :(

Comment: @jmspaggi One billion of these (with an added modulo and concat) take me about 12 minutes @ 3.4 GHz. 2/3 are spent within DateTimeFormatter. Use a parallel Stream and you won't have to worry.

Comment: I didn't really count how many I have ;) It's a huge streaming job running on the cloud getting information from all around the world for a big company. My point what that it's very big, and if I can get it down from 12 minutes to 6 minutes, well, they will probably take it. As well as I was hoping to make that even more easy to ready. In your test are you recreating the ofPattern into your loop? Or outside of the loop? I will probably end up doing something like what you posted, but I was really hopping getting the Myyyy format work :(

Comment: Taking ofPattern out of the loop and using a parallel Stream with 7 threads, we're now clocking in at about 160 seconds per billion.